# ASP.NET MVC Automatic Model Instantiation if Model is not provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, model

I'm trying to achieve auto instantiation of view models when they are not given (when they are null).

*Controller Action*

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View("~/.../SomeView.cshtml"); //No model is given
}
```

*SomeView.cshtml*

```
@model Models.SomeModel //According to this type...
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
//...auto instantiate @Model when it is null
```

I've tried to override RazorViewEngine, but it seems (I may be wrong) at the ViewEngine time I cannot access the model type, it is always null, even if it is provided. And I should be able to learn type of the null model since we are trying to instantiate it, so there should be another Metadata which for us to get the View's Model type.

I've tried extending DefaultModelBinder, but it seems it is only for binding models from an Http request, it didn't fire on manual view creation.

I'm out of ideas. I hope it is feasible to do.

Comment: Why?  This seems like an awful lot of effort to avoid using a  few keystrokes.

Comment: You are assuming it is a few keystrokes my friend, there may be hundreds of reasons why someone needs that. If we would have asked "why do it instead of a few keystrokes?" we would never have ASP.NET MVC today. However, if you really wonder: I have many partial views, all the HTML is divided in the project. I don't want to instantiate dozens of view models in View files by Html.Partial('x.cshtml', new Model()). I don't want to mix them in models since they are used in many places. I'll be also adding automatic View inclusion by Html.Partial and I want to get rid of model instantiation.

Comment: You didn't say anything about Partials in your question.  Partials work very differently than views do.  Any solution that would work for a view would not work for a Partial.  In any event, how exactly do you expect some code to magically know what's necessary to instantiate your view model?  You could certainly write a function that would parse the view, and look for an @model statement, then dynamically instantiate it, but that would only work for simple models that require no additional setup.  Hardly worth the effort for something that only works with 10% of the code

Comment: Besides, you generally don't need to instantiate a default model because the Html helper functions deal with null models for you in most cases, and the cases where they don't, you'd have to use custom configuration anyways that couldn't be automatically instantiated.

Comment: I don't like you "It doesn't work/worth/needed" people. We solved it, see the answer below.

Comment: And what does that gain you really?  Now, it's *IMPOSSIBLE* to send a null model, even if you want one.  It only works with basic models that require no additional data (ie can only contain default data).  This is pointless because MVC deals with null models perfectly fine on with it's helper methods.  The only reason you would want this is if you didn't understand the right way to use MVC.  On top of that, you've created a confusing situation where anyone else that looks at the code won't understand what its doing, because you've broken the cardinal rule of MVC, Conventions.

Comment: I have never needed to pass null models. This is my special case, every application is different and I'm developing something different. Not everything is black and white. FYI, there's a reason it is called "Convention over configuration", you are allowed to change the convention with the configuration. The code is much more clean now and understandable right now. You don't use something like this in your projects, I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of BorysG we have solved it, I've also improved it to work with Partials.

Discussion: http://forums.asp.net/t/1924332.aspx/1?ASP+NET+MVC+Automatic+Model+Instantiation+if+Model+is+not+provided

Copying the code here also:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        var view = base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);

        return new ViewWrapper(view);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var view = base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);

        return new ViewWrapper(view);
    }
}

public class ViewWrapper : IView
{
    protected IView View;

    public ViewWrapper(IView view)
    {
        View = view;
    }

    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {
        //Type modelType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(razorView.ViewPath);
        var razorView = View as RazorView;

        if (razorView != null)
        {
            //if we could not get the model object - try to get it from what is declared in view
            var compiledViewType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(razorView.ViewPath);

            var model = viewContext.ViewData.Model;

            Type baseType = compiledViewType.BaseType;
            //model is passed as generic parameter, like this MyView1 : WebViewPage<MyModel1>
            if (baseType != null && baseType.IsGenericType)
            {
                //and here the trick begins - extract type of model from generic arguments
                var modelType = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //the same as typeof(MyModel1)

                // ReSharper disable UseMethodIsInstanceOfType
                //If model is null, or model is not type of the given model (for partials)
                if (model == null || !modelType.IsAssignableFrom(model.GetType()))
                // ReSharper restore UseMethodIsInstanceOfType
                {
                    //Set @model and render the view
                    viewContext.ViewData.Model = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
                }
            }
        }

        View.Render(viewContext, writer);
    }
}
```

And also into Global.asax.cs in the Application_Start().

```
//remove default Razor and WebForm view engines
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```